# Get node fields in Rules action programatically

Tags: 8, rules

How to get node field values and include it the Rules Action? If I have a custom content type that has taxonomy terms, and I want to display these terms in Action. Example output is simply logging the terms.

- Event: content type is created
- Condition: of node type: custom_content
- Action: Log the taxonomy terms

Pseudo code:

```
 public function execute() {
    $term1 = field_taxonomy1_fromCustomContentType
    $term2 = field_taxonomy2_fromCustomContentType
    $this->setProvidedValue('concatenated', $term1 . $term2);
    \Drupal::logger('custom_rules')->notice("Rules Action");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone had the same approach as mine. Here is the solution from Drupal.org [community](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2952453).